# Pandas histogram from count of columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have a big dataframe that consist of about 6500 columns where one is a classlabel and the rest are boolean values of either 0 or 1, the dataframe is sparse.

example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
            'label' : ['a', 'b', 'c', 'b','a', 'c', 'b', 'a'],
            'x1' : np.random.choice(2, 8),
            'x2' : np.random.choice(2, 8),
            'x3' : np.random.choice(2, 8)})
```

What I want is a report (preferably in pandas so I can plot it easily) that shows me the sum of unique elements of the columns grouped by the label.

So for example this data frame:

```
    x1  x2  x3  label
0   0   1   1   a
1   1   0   1   b
2   0   1   0   c
3   1   0   0   b
4   1   1   1   a
5   0   0   1   c
6   1   0   0   b
7   0   1   0   a
```

The result should be something like this:

```
a: 3 (since it has x1, x2 and x3)
b: 2 (since it has x1, x3)
c: 2 (since it has x2, x3)
```

So it's kind of a count of which columns are present in each label. Think of a histogram where the x-axis is the `label` and the y-axis the `number of columns`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try pivoting:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({
        'label' : ['a', 'b', 'c', 'b','a', 'c', 'b', 'a'],
        'x1' : np.random.choice(2, 8),
        'x2' : np.random.choice(2, 8),
        'x3' : np.random.choice(2, 8)})

pd.pivot_table(df, index='label').transpose().apply(np.count_nonzero)
```

For df:

```
label   x1  x2  x3
0   a   0   0   0
1   b   0   1   0
2   c   1   0   1
3   b   0   1   0
4   a   1   1   1
5   c   1   0   1
6   b   0   1   0
7   a   1   1   1
```

The result is:

```
label
a    3
b    1
c    2
dtype: int64
```

Comment: Awesome solution. Love that it sticks to the pandas/numpy enviroment and it's incredibly fast as well. Thanks for giving me insight into pivoting as well. Never used it before

Comment: Thinking about it, you can remove the transpose and just use axis=1 in the apply. Glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

```
label = df.groupby('label')
for key,val in label.count()['x1'].iteritems():
    strg = '%s:%s' %(key,val)
    for col,vl in label.sum().ix[key].iteritems():
        if vl!=0:
            strg += ' %s'%col
    print strg
```